# Possible to share cache item amongst multiple windows services?

Tags: c#, caching, windows-services, asp.net-4.5, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to share a cached item amongst several windows services?

```
 List<GetPortedNumbersResult> col = (List<GetPortedNumbersResult>)result.ToList();

 var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
 CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
 cache.Add(new CacheItem("PortedCol", col), policy);
```

Comment: Yep. You'd have to architect it differently though, i.e. host a cache in a separate windows service and have your other windows services talk to it (maybe via WCF or something similar)... or use a purpose made distributed cache line Memcached or Velocity, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian Thompson Phillips hit the nail on the head with a distributed cache.  I think that will be your best bet.

The only thing I'll add, is that I would consider App Fabric (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) since it's Microsoft's version of a distributed cache.

You can even run App Fabric nodes on the same machine that has the Windows services. You don't need dedicated cache nodes in the cluster.